# Deleted sql database recreated

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

A while ago I created a test database using the Azure portal. I deleted it manually in the portal and saw confirmation of successful deletion. After a couple of days I can see the database is there again. This repeated several times, resulting in high charges.
I don't have any automatics deployments configured, nor performed any other manual operations.

1. I consider this to be an Azure bug - where to report it?
2. How can I request billing update request?

Comment: Firts check the activity log of that resource to see the history, and if you dont see nothing open a ticket on the azure portal, Help + Support! Good luck

Comment: Check the Activity Log on your resources. Everything is logged for 90 days. Then if you consider somthing being wrong report to Microsoft using the Support & Help in the portal

Comment: Hi @Filip, did you get any progresses? If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's the error we can not repeat it. We also can not give you the solution directly.

Please follow the suggestions provided by @Nacho Martínez-Aedo and @Daniel Bjork:

1. Check the Activity Log on your resources, the max timespan is 90 days:
   [image]
2. Report to Microsoft using the Support & Help in the Portal, you can follow the template bellow:
   [image]

Please provide more details about the issue in Details.

Comment: with Basic plan I cannot create support request for technical issues.